# Rank-revealing transform to identity*

Tags: linear-transformations, matrix-rank

how to calculate below matrices M and N for a (possibly singular) square matrix E?

As a bonus, the method should be applicable to E containing symbolic variables.

[Rank-revealing transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpBs0.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your equations instead of a hypertext link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a $n\times n$ matrix of rank $r$ over the field $k$. Let $x_{r+1}, \ldots, x_n$ be a basis of $\ker E$ and complete it into a basis $x_1,\ldots, x_r,x_{r+1},\ldots, x_n$ of $k^n$. Let :$$ N = \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & x_n\end{array}\right)$$

Then, we have :
\begin{align}
EN &= \left(\begin{array}{c|c} Ex_1 & Ex_2 & \ldots & Ex_n\end{array}\right) \\
&= \left(\begin{array}{c|c} y_1 & \ldots & y_r & 0 & \ldots & 0\end{array}\right)
\end{align}

where $y_1,\ldots,y_r$ is a set of linearly independent vectors. Complete it into a basis $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ of $k^n$, then set :
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} y_1 & y_2 & \ldots & y_n\end{array}\right)$$
so that :
$$EN = M \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\  0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
i.e.
$$E = M \begin{pmatrix} I_r & 0 \\  0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}N^{-1}$$

If $E$ contains formal variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, just extends the base field to the rational fractions $k(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, so the above algorithm works.

**Algorithms** You need two sub-algorithms : one to compute a basis of $\ker E$ (a quick search seem to indicate that Mathlab has a [built-in function](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html)) and another one to extend a linearly independent family into a basis (see the different answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391740/algorithm-to-effectively-extend-basis)).

Comment: Thanks so much SolubleFish for your elaborate answer.
For the not so exposed engineering folks like me, how would this translate into Matlab?

Comment: I am not familiar with Matlab, so I am afraid I cannot help you more. I think you could ask the issue of implementation in another post (though it might be off-topic in MSE)

Comment: replace "Matlab" by "algorithm"

Comment: I edited my answer to include a comment on algorithms to do this.

Comment: OK - Thank you very much!